# How do I count the number of words in a string?

Tags: java, string

I need to count the number of words and I am assuming the correct way to do it is by calculating the number of times that the previous character in a string is not a letter (ie other characters) because this is to assume that there would be colons,spaces,tabs, and other signs in the string.
So at first my idea was to loop through each character and count how many times that you will not get a letter of an alphabet

```
    for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
      for(int j = 0; i < alphabets.length(); j++) {
       if (string.charAt(i-1) == alphabets.charAt(j)) {
           counter++;
       }
     }
   }
```

However I will always get an array out of bounds because of this. So, I kinda need a little help or another way that can actually be more efficient.
I thought of using Matches to only [a-zA-z] but I'm not sure how do I handle a char to be comparable to a string in counting how many times it occurs.

Thank you

Comment: There's only one word in java.

Comment: Is this a count of *all* words, or only *unique* words?

Comment: all words, but assuming some words have some words appear after a space,hyphens,colons etc etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suggestion to use a regex like "[A-Za-z]" would work fine.  In a split command, you'd split on the inverse, like:

String[] words = "Example test: one, two, three".split("[^A-Za-z]+");

EDIT:  If you're just looking for raw speed, this'll do the job more quickly.

```
public static int countWords(String str) {
    char[] sentence = str.toCharArray();
    boolean inWord = false;
    int wordCt = 0;
    for (char c : sentence) {
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' || c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
            if (!inWord) {
                wordCt++;
                inWord = true;
            }
        } else {
            inWord = false;
        }
    }
    return wordCt;
}
```

Comment: So far I think by splitting them up is a more efficient way. And I think it will make it easier for me to solve the next task as well. It does require more processing time but I think I have no other option for now.

Comment: +1 - This is exactly the algorithm I had in mind (that you've code for).  @nfnmy The split approach has corner cases which will fail and it is also slower.  I'm not sure I understand why you would elect to use it.

Comment: yeah this is a really efficient code. But I think I will use the split method for now which kinda makes my task easier in terms of manipulating them in an array for other calculations for statistical purposes. Thank you phatfingers. I will definitely keep this one for references as I have not seen this algorithm before. cheers genius!

Comment: @nfnmy, I'll be sure to mention your name in my acceptance speech for the Nobel Prize I'm bound to receive for such amazing advancements in the parsing sciences.  Heh.  Glad I could be of some help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to convert the string into an array, with one word in each element.  The number of words is given by the length of the array:

```
int words = myString.split("\s+").length;
```

Comment: Count?  The array has a `length` property.

Comment: And maybe use a regex to split like `\s+`.

Comment: so I should try splitting this long string into an array based on if the character matches other than [a-zA-Z],hmmm..

Comment: Better to use Rob I's suggestion to split on whitespace.

Comment: This doesn't work if the string starts with whitespace.  The empty string will appear as the first element, counting as a word, but it should not.

Comment: This is a simple example.  You can handle edge cases with `trim()`, or by actually inspecting each string in the resulting array and deciding whether it's a valid word (perhaps you'd want to ignore numbers or punctuation with no accompanying letters).

Answer (score 2):

This problem is slightly more complicated than your algorithm allows.

- What if there are two or more spaces in a row?
- What if the string starts or ends with whitespace (or non-word characters)?

This looks like homework, so I don't want to provide any code.  I suggest an alternative approach which is simpler to think about.

- Walk through the characters in the string, one by one.
- Do something to remember if you are currently scanning a word or if you are not currently scanning a word.
- Do something to determine when you enter or leave a word, and increment your counter accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Yeah I'm not really expecting any codes, just merely more tips and how I can tackle this problem more efficiently. Don't really enjoy being spoonfed with answers.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is probably because when i is 0 your inner loop will have `string.charAt(i-1)` which will throw an exception since 0-1 is -1.  If you fix that your method might work, although you can use more efficient techniques.

Answer (score 1):

Addressing the code directly, your first loop has *i*=0 as the first value of *i*, but then you ask for

> string.charAt(i-1) = string.charAt(-1),

which is where your array-out-of-bounds is coming from.

The second loop has another problem:

> for(int j = 0; *i* < alphabets.length(); j++) {

You may also want to consider apostrophes as parts of words as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Use just like this**

```
String s = "I am Juyel Rana, from Bangladesh";
int count = s.split(" ").length;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   if (string.charAt(i-1) == alphabets.charAt(j)) {
       counter++;
   }
```

You are incrementing the counter if the character is *some* alphabet character. You should increment it if it is *no* alphabet character.

Answer (score 0):

The following program will count the number of words in a sentence. In this program, we are counting alphabets just after space. The alphabet can be of lower case or upper case. We are inserting a space at the beginning since people don't start a sentence with space. We also need to take care that any special character or number should not be counted as a word.

`import java.util.Scanner;
public class WordSent {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the sentence");
    String str=in.nextLine();
    String space=" ";
    String spaceword=space.concat(str);

    int count=0;
    for(int i=0; i<spaceword.length()-1;i++)
    {
        for (int k=0; k<=25; k++)
        {
        if(spaceword.charAt(i)==' '&& (spaceword.charAt(i+1)==((char)(65+k)) || spaceword.charAt(i+1)==((char)(97+k))))
        {
            count++;
        }
      }
     }
    System.out.println("Total number of words in a sentence are" +" :  "+   count);
     }
    }`
```